# Webservice - DateTime Error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to check if my webservice is running well. All other ones is ok but whenever i run this particular one i get an error. In my database the datatype for DateOfBirth is 'datetime' also for DateApplied is 'datetime'. But whenever i want to check it on my browser to see if it is working i get this error message:

```
System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
   at FinalService.getfinal() in c:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\DevinApp\App_Code\FinalService.cs:line 26
```

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class FinalService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public void getfinal()
        {
            var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NNPC-ChevronScholarshipConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            var students = new List<Final>();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("getapplicants", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
                con.Open();
                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var student = new Final
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                        ApplicationID = dr[1].ToString(),
                        FirstName = dr[2].ToString(),
                        MiddleName = dr[3].ToString(),
                        LastName = dr[4].ToString(),
                        DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[5].ToString()),

                        Gender = dr[6].ToString(),
                        Phone = dr[7].ToString(),
                        Email = dr[8].ToString(),
                        DateApplied = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[9].ToString()),
                        CurrentLevel = dr[10].ToString(),
                        MatricNo = dr[11].ToString()

                    };
                    students.Add(student);
                }
            }
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(students));
        }

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `dr[5].ToString()`? What is the datatype of the that column in the database? _Also the same for `dr[9]`._

Comment: the datatype is datetime

Comment: I asked four questions, and you answered one. Can you answer all four?

Comment: Please show us the `getapplicants` stored proc.

Comment: no value for dr[5] is pointing to the column in my database

Answer (score 2):

It means that was is being returned by `dr[5].ToString()` is not a valid `DateTime`.  It encounters "an unknown word at index 0" - that means the very first character of the string is not valid for `DateTime`s.

I would look for bad data in that column in the database.

Edit:

Also, it's not necessary to convert to string.  You can convert directly from a SQL `DateTime` to a C# `DateTime`.  Something very similar to this should work:

```
 dr.GetDateTime(5);
```

Comment: i have tried dr.GetDateTime(5); I am getting this error: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_DateTime()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDateTime(Int32 i)

Comment: That probably means that you have bad data in your database.  I would run a SQL query to select that column from all rows and look at the results.  If some of them don't look like DateTimes then that is the problem.